# Name of the Minimum value in a named vector

Tags: r

I have a named vector:

```
v <- c("morning"=80, "noon"=20, "night"=40)
```

printing `min(v)` gives

> [1] 20

I want to get this instead:

> noon
>       20

Is there a simple way?

Comment: `v[which.min(v)]`, or if you just want the name, `names(v)[which.min(v)]`.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking for just the name, so `names(which.min(v))` works for me great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`v[which.min(v)]` will give you the output you listed. But if you just want the name, and not the value, then do `names(v)[which.min(v)]`.